# Doctrine(2.12) keeps generating the same migration for a property using columnDefinition

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created an apiplatform 3.0, symfony 6.1 app.
It has a docker environment with mysql 8.0.

Using the new features in doctrine 2.11, I created 2 properties:

```php
trait TraitName
{
    #[ORM\Column(insertable: false, updatable: false, columnDefinition: 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', generated: 'INSERT')]
    private \DateTimeImmutable $createdAt;

    #[ORM\Column(insertable: false, updatable: false, columnDefinition: 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', generated: 'ALWAYS')]
    private \DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt;
}
```

They also have their own getter.

When I make a migration and migrate. Everything goes well. The app is running fine.
But everytime I do `doctrine:schema:validate`, it says `The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.`
And if I do a `make:migration` it keeps on creating the same migration:

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE created_at created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE table2 CHANGE created_at created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE table3 CHANGE created_at created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CHANGE updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
```

I tried moving it out of the trait, it does not change anything.

I read that it could be the serverVersion or an issue with the driver definition(when using mariaDb which it is not the case here)
The DATABASE_URL is defined as such in the compose.yaml:

```yaml
DATABASE_URL: mysql://user:password@database:3306/dbname?serverVersion=5.7
```

doctrine.yaml:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```